Unsatisfied with Undergraduate Education
For the most part I would say I've always enjoyed math. In high school I took classes ahead of my peers and had two great teachers that made learning math easy. After high school I wanted to study math and eventually pursue a PHD.
I’m in my third year at a small university studying mathematics and computer science. I don’t feel satisfied with my undergraduate mathematics education. In our math department there is only one professor with a PHD who teaches all the upper-division math courses like real analysis. The professor is not a great teacher, so it is hard to learn from them. Many times, when I ask for help it doesn’t seem like the professor wants to help which is very frustrating. Many times, I walk away feeling like I wasted my time even asking for help. There are also no tutors, and the classes usually only have 1-2 people so the only person to ask for help is the professor. I feel like I did learn because I know more now than when I started my undergraduate studies, but I’m worried I won’t be prepared for graduate school. I feel like there are students at other schools taking more advanced courses than what my school offers and doing research. Due to this I feel like I'll be at a disadvantage and be behind the rest of the pack in graduate school.
This has been stressing me out and I've been considering if CS is the way to go for me. I don't feel like giving up but I'm feeling burnt out.
I’m not sure if this is just something everyone goes through or if it’s just me. Is there anyone who feels the same way?
What should I do to prepare for graduate school given these circumstances?
How should I go about learning upper-division math with a difficult professor? Thank you!

How possible would it be to change universities now?

I'm basically finished with the degree so I don't think it would be financially smart. I only have like one more class left to take that my school offers.

Since classes are small, are the other students also grad school material and how possible would it be to work with them as a group?

You make the best of what you have. Your ability to explore and self-educate  is expected, so spend time improving that aspect.

What country are you in? Some things sound like US, others not.

@Buffy I don't think the other students are pursuing graduate school. I attend a university in the U.S.

Will you have had at least Analysis (Real & Complex), Abstract Algebra, and General Topology, with decent grades?

I will have taken both real analysis, and complex analysis. I took an abstract algebra course but it was applied. My school doesn’t offer a general topology course. I figure that I’m going to have to self study abstract algebra and some more real analysis and complex analysis. In my real analysis class we don’t cover everything so I think I will need to learn some more on my own.

Why did you attend this university? Did your interests change? Did they downsize their Math department? Did you not look up their Math program before enrolling? Did other universities reject you?

Just to check, because it isn't universal, and you might not know what you're missing out on if you're missing out on it: Do your upper level math courses expect you to come up with proofs that are not just minor variants of proofs you have already seen?  As the most important skill you should take away from the course?  More or less on your own without too many hints (which is not the same as with no hints)?

You are in a tough situation. I also went to a small liberal arts college in the US. It had about 2000 students then, but has grown. We had good and bad professors but the good ones made up for the others. Note that in the US, grad applications rely fairly heavily on letters of recommendation, and I don't know if that will be an issue for you.
I normally suggest that students go directly from undergraduate to doctoral programs, partly because that is generally the norm (US) and partly because doctoral study is funded through teaching assistantships. Masters study rarely is funded.
Perhaps you should consider applying for both doctoral study and masters study (different institutions) simultaneously. A course based masters would make "hole filling" possible, though the funding would be from you. Your situation is also unusual (US) to be "complete" in the third year. Usually it takes four. And, it is also usual here to have the undergrad program very broad based beyond any major subject. That is unlike, say, Germany, where it is very focused on one subject. If your program is unusual in other ways then it might cause additional problems.
Math is very difficult to study on your own as a novice. It is hard to gain insight without guidance (and hard work). In reading your post, it is also hard to parse the issue with your advisor. You and I might have the same issue that you and your advisor do, but that is because when you would come to me for guidance and asking questions, I would try hard to give you minimal answers rather than complete ones. I might point out where you went wrong, rather than how to get right. I might point out a block. I might send you off for a reading. The purpose of such a style and philosophy is that the insight comes from working it out yourself, not from hearing or reading the answers of others. Math is a (very) active sport. It requires changing your brain physically, creating new pathways. Reading and listening are never enough until you gain the insight. Perhaps that is the real issue with the advisor and you are interpreting it as "not caring". Not necessarily, but a possibility.
To enter grad school you will need good letters of recommendation, one almost certainly from this advisor. Do what you can to cultivate a good relationship.
When it comes to applying for grad study, cast a wide net. There are many good schools with a "ranking" around 50 or so. Don't apply to just top schools. One hint, is to determine if some recent math graduate of your school has gone somewhere and done very well. Consider applying to the same institution.
As to how to do well in courses with minimal guidance, it is very difficult. Find textbooks with lots of exercises and do as many of them as you can. Some books have answers given for alternate exercises so that you can compare your solution to the one provided. Don't just read the solutions, though, as it is nearly useless. And, solve a lot of the problems. Learning depends on both repetition and feedback, though you indicate the feedback from the instructor is weak. Online courses that don't provide feedback is too passive for real, insightful, learning.
If permitted, working groups of students can be helpful, provided that you adhere to the rules set. But you can study together and give feedback to one another in most cases.
I'll keep thinking about this for a bit. Maybe I can come up with something.

Additionally, the OP might find All the Mathematics You Missed (But Need to Know for Graduate School) by Thomas A. Garrity (2nd edition, 2021) helpful in assessing his/her background. There are 468 reviews at amazon.com, a rather high number for a mathematics book, especially for a mathematics book that is beyond the elementary calculus, linear algebra, ODE level. Incidentally, I looked at a few low rated reviews, and many seem to be criticizing the book for things it was not designed for.

@DaveLRenfro thank you for this suggestion. I’ll definitely look into this book!


there is only one professor with a PHD who teaches all the upper division math courses like real analysis. The professor is not a great teacher, so it is hard to learn from them

I think it's normal to experience particular professors/teachers that are not a good fit for you in the course of an education. In some cases, that may indeed be because they are "not a great teacher"; in other cases, it may just be that their teaching style does not fit well with your learning style.
In your particular case, though, this is having an unusually large impact on you because all the upper division math courses are taught by one person. This seems like a disadvantage of attending the type of institution you are attending, so it's also a consequence of that choice that you made.
If you are scheduled to have more classes with this same person, it seems like it would be reasonable to consider transferring if that is an option available to you.

I don’t think transferring would be financially feasible at this point. I’m almost finished with the degree. I only have one or two classes left to take. I feel like I have to self study a lot but it feels overwhelming because I don’t know how to efficiently do it to get myself prepared.

Aren't learning styles a myth?

@DavidWhite I meant to broadly reference that different students mesh differently with different instructors, not Learning Styles as in "this student is an auditory learner" etc. The latter is debunked, I'm not aware that the former is.
